# Neural Network: Convert HTML Table into JSON data

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, deep-learning

I'm kinda new to Neural Networks and just started to learn coding them by trying some examples.
Two weeks ago I was searching for an interesting challenge and I found one. But I'm about to give up because it seems to be too hard for me... But I was curious to know if anyone of you is able to solve this?

**The Problem:** Assume there are ".htm"-files that contain tables about the same topic. But the table structure isn't the same for every file. For example: We have a lot ".htm"-files containing information about teachers substitutions per day per school. Because the structure of those ".htm"-files isn't the same for every file it would be hard to program a parser that could extract the data from those tables. So my thought was that this is a task for a Neural Network.

**First Question:** Is it a task a Neural Network can/should handle or am I mistaken by that?

Because for me a Neural Network seemed to fit for this kind of a challenge I tried to thing of an Input. I came up with two options:

**First Input Option:** Take the HTML Code (only from the body-tag) as string and convert it as Tensor

**Second Input Option:** Convert the HTML Tables into Images (via Canvas maybe) and feed this input to the DNN through Conv2D-Layers.

**Second Question:** Are those Options any good? Do you have any better solution to this?

After that I wanted to figure out how I would make a DNN output this heavily dynamic data for me? My thought was to convert my desired JSON-Output into Tensors and feed them to the DNN while training and for every prediction i would expect the DNN to return a Tensor that is convertible into a JSON-Output...

**Third Question:** Is it even possible to get such a detailed Output from a DNN? And if Yes: Do you think the Output would be suitable for this task?

**Last Question:** Assuming all my assumptions are correct - Wouldn't training this DNN take for ever? Let's say you have a RTX 2080 ti for it. What would you guess?

I guess that's it. I hope i can learn a lot from you guys!

(I'm sorry about my bad English - it's not my native language)

**Addition:**

Here is a more in-depth Example. Lets say we have a ".htm"-file that looks like this:
[image: Example of an .html-file]

The task would be to get all the relevant informations from this table. For example:
All Students from Class "9c" don't have lessons in their 6th hour due to cancellation.

Answer (score 2):

1) This is not particularly suitable problem for a Neural Network, as you domain is a structured data with clear dependcies inside. Tree based ML algorithms tend to show much better results on such problems.

2) Both you choices of input are very unstructured. To learn from such data would be nearly impossible. The are clear ways to give more knowledge to the model. For example, you have the same data in different format, the difference is only the structure. It means that a model needs to learn a mapping from one structure to another, it doesn't need to know any data. Hence, words can be Tokenized with unique identifiers to remove unnecessary information. Htm data can be parsed to a tree, as well as json. Then, there are different ways to represent graph structures, which can be used in a ML model.

3) It seems that the only adequate option for output is a sequence of identifiers pointing to unique entities from text. The whole problem then is similar to Seq2Seq best solved by RNNs with an decoder-encoder architecture.

I believe that, if there is enough data and htm files don't have huge amount of noise, the task can be completed. Training time hugely depends on selected model and its complexity, as well as diversity of initial data.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I guess I have chosen a tough challenge... I don't quite understand how i could make use of an RNN/seq2seq Model... I've seen some videos on it but... Is there anything you would recommend me to read or learn so i can master this specific challenge?
Also: I've edited my answer and added a more specific example...
Thank you for your extensive assessment!